# SetTimeout method with scroll listener

Tags: javascript, settimeout, addeventlistener

I have an eventListener("scroll") function that triggers a class when the user scrolls down 25px.  If the user does nothing the class is never triggered.  How do I set a timeout function that will trigger the class after 5s if the user never scrolls?

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  let sat = document.querySelector(".hero-images--sat");
  let scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
  const images = document.querySelectorAll(".hero-image");

  if ((scrolled += 25)) {
    sat.classList.add("appear");
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    let pos = scrolled * images[i].dataset.rate;

    if (images[i].classList.contains("hero-images--earth")) {
      let pos = scrolled * images[i].dataset.rate - 48.75;
      images[i].style.transform = `translate3d(-50%, ${pos}%, 0px)`;
    } else {
      images[i].style.transform = `translate3d(0%, ${pos}%, 0px)`;
    }
  }
});

.appear {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the timeout after the user scrolled. Take a look at this:

After you scrolled 25px `addClass()` will be called. If you do not scroll, it will be called after 5 seconds.

```js
function addClass() {
  let sat = document.querySelector(".hero-images--sat");
  sat.classList.add("appear");
}
let timer = setTimeout(addClass, 5000);
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {  
  let scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
  if (scrolled >= 25) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    addClass();
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  height: 100px;
}

.appear {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>foo</p>
<p class="hero-images--sat">foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
<p>foo</p>
```

Btw: Check your if: `if ((scrolled += 25))`. `+=` is probably not want you want.

Comment: Thank you!  This works.  One small issue though, after scrolling, at the 5 second mark, the scroll starts to freeze for a second.  Do you know why this is?

Comment: @RRhodes Does this happen only in your code or also in my example? Can't reproduce it in the latter.

Comment: Only in my code, sorry.  There's a lot more going on in the actual project.

Comment: Hmm. Without knowing the rest of the code, I can not help you with this. Sorry. Maybe you will ask a new question for this if you are able to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).